# Java Inner Classes for creating Event Handlers and Renderers

Tags: java, inner-classes, eventhandler

**Which of the following statements are true for - Inner Classes?**

1. Inner Classes are not permitted in Java
2. Event Handlers, renderers etc can be created using Inner Classes
3. Small handlers for eg. Comparator, Thread etc. can be defined using an Inner Class
4. Only Static Inner Classes are permitted in Java

Can anybody please help me finding out which of the following statements are true (more than one statement can be true). I got this question today at my test.

The first option is false because Java permits inner class.

The last option is also false because I have read that Nested Class are of two types *Static Nested Class* and *Non Static Nested Class*. Non-static nested classes are more formally known as Inner Classes.

I am confused about the second and third option because I have never used inner classes for Event Handlers or Renderers. Can anyone please help me understand how Inner Classes can be used for these purposes. An example or a link to a article would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Inner Classes are not permitted in Java

False

> Event Handlers, renderers etc can be created using Inner Classes

True

> Small handlers for eg. Comparator, Thread etc. can be defined using an Inner Class

True

> Only Static Inner Classes are permitted in Java

False